# texlive 2022 failed to install

Tags: lyx, texlive, overleaf, latex3, texlive-2020

I installed texlive 2021 iso several times in windows 10 and no problems. but when I try to install texlive 2022 iso I found the following :

```
Installing to: C:/texlive/2022
Installing [1/6, time/total: ??:??/??:??]: hyphen-base [22k]
Installing [2/6, time/total: 00:00/00:00]: kpathsea [1087k]
Installing [3/6, time/total: 00:01/00:10]: luatex [1870k]
Installing [4/6, time/total: 00:01/00:03]: texlive-scripts [504k]
Installing [5/6, time/total: 00:02/00:06]: texlive.infra [545k]
Installing [6/6, time/total: 00:02/00:05]: tlperl.win32 [7112k]
Time used for installing the packages: 00:08
Installing [0001/4328, time/total: ??:??/??:??]: 12many [376k]
Installing [0002/4328, time/total: 00:02/05:30:51]: 2up [56k]
Installing [0003/4328, time/total: 00:03/07:12:29]: a0poster [119k]
Installing [0004/4328, time/total: 00:03/05:39:04]: a2ping [69k]
Installing [0005/4328, time/total: 00:03/05:01:20]: a2ping.win32 [1k]
Installing [0006/4328, time/total: 00:04/06:41:21]: a4wide [133k]
Installing [0007/4328, time/total: 00:04/05:30:30]: a5comb [91k]
Installing [0008/4328, time/total: 00:05/06:08:43]: aaai-named [6k]
Installing [0009/4328, time/total: 00:05/06:06:31]: aalok [187k]
Installing [0010/4328, time/total: 00:07/07:00:36]: aastex [1188k]
Installing [0011/4328, time/total: 00:08/03:43:33]: abbr [4k]
Installing [0012/4328, time/total: 00:08/03:43:12]: abc [288k]
Installing [0013/4328, time/total: 00:09/03:42:23]: abnt [121k]
Installing [0014/4328, time/total: 00:10/03:55:49]: abntex2 [4508k]
Installing [0015/4328, time/total: 00:11/01:35:37]: aboensis [34288k]
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove: checksums differ for C:\Users\Mohammed\AppData\Local\Temp\PtXQZX5YpB\D0xMfYkYK5/aboensis.doc.r60059.tar.xz:
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove:   tlchecksum=26734c8b7f69e0265edb71e3c62c8a9246a45b2b9fcc15975c2489edd1767f308a280c5221a14594382c1c9bb88138785d549aadb01969413f2c32bf5880b439, arg=32189a8bd005651ed2b99c367111839acf2595fc8375e1984d8f45f278b2d88d4da3fcad64676baa3dcb91955055f5fd30608f7f7d26cd13a9f10fb5421882b6
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove: backtrace:
 -> J://tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm:2527: TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove
 -> J://tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1983: TeXLive::TLUtils::unpack
 -> J://tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1854: TeXLive::TLPDB::_install_data
 -> J://tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1734: TeXLive::TLPDB::not_virtual_install_package
 -> J://tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm:1726: TeXLive::TLPDB::install_package
 -> J://install-tl:2191: TeXLive::TLUtils::install_packages
 -> J://install-tl:997: main::do_install_packages
 -> J://install-tl:715: main::do_installation
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove:   removing C:\Users\Mohammed\AppData\Local\Temp\PtXQZX5YpB\D0xMfYkYK5/aboensis.doc.r60059.tar.xz, but saving copy in C:\Users\Mohammed\AppData\Local\Temp\XW8QnW9Svr
TLPDB::_install_data: consistency checks failed for J:/archive/aboensis.doc.r60059.tar.xz
TLUtils::install_packages: Failed to install aboensis
Installation failed.
Rerunning the installer will try to restart the installation.
Or you can restart by running the installer with:
  install-tl-windows.bat --profile installation.profile [YOUR-EXTRA-ARGS]
J://install-tl: Writing log in current directory: C:/WINDOWS/system32/install-tl.log
```

I did a format and reinstall windows 10 again and had the same result. thank you all of helping.